# Display image from database with the type binary/byte[]

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, binaryfiles

Ive stored an image with memorystream to my database, but now i want to display the image in the view but since its the type of binary i dont really know how and im trying to convert it from string. i think i have enough code in the controller which will enable me to display the image but i dont know how to display it.

another important thing is that i need to show this image in the _ViewStart.cshtml, so it will appear on everysite. (PageData["LogoUrl"] = "imagefromdatabase";)

this is how far ive been able to do:

```
    public void Show( Models.EditLogoModel MLogo, int id, object data)
    {
        var service = ServiceFactory.Instance.CreateLogoService();

        if (data != null)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            {
                Byte[] LOGO = MLogo.DBLogo.PicImgData;
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = MLogo.DBLogo.PicImgData.ToString();
                Response.BinaryWrite(LOGO);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: See [DOWNLOAD AND UPLOAD IMAGES FROM SQL SERVER VIA ASP.NET MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: @RemusRusanu im sry but i dont want to upload or download, i want to display the image which means i need to convert from binary to something that will show the image

Comment: That would qualify as a "download". The example shows how to do that.